Fatal: bad object refs/heads/main 2 error: https://github.com/xxx did not send all necessary objects
I am using windows 11 (64 bits), on a galaxy book2 360, Texstudio and Gihub. I am cloning the github repository on my cloud. It works for one day and suddenly I receive the message in the title. Please send me ideas for a better configuration.
I am expecting to have a good respository backup for may latex document.

What do you mean by "cloning (...) on my cloud"? I doubt that is a good idea, as git files and the cloning mechanisms could interfere in a bad way. Why not clone to a local folder?

I have the same suspicion. I will test cloning locally!
